# Does Java Apache HttpClient reuse keepalive connection?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, keep-alive, session-reuse

I have nginx with enabled keepalive. I create simple java code, which sends 2 requests to nginx:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var apacheHttpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setConnectionManager(new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager())
                .build();

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://127.0.0.1:5000");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            try (CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = apacheHttpClient.execute(httpGet)) {
                System.out.println(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked with wireshark that the java program creates 2 connection to execute this command. Why Java apache httpclient do not reuse connection? I assume that 1 connection should be established and be reused.[image]

Comment: Does the nginx set a Keep-Alive header in the response? IIUC, it should reuse the connection if there is no Keep-Alive header anyways, but I'm not sure about that.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68990038/apache-httpclient-keep-alive-strategy-for-active-connections

Comment: yes, Nginx set a keep-alive header in the response

Comment: OK, then what's the value of the keep-alive header?

Comment: Keep alive is set to 2000ms - confirmed by debug logs